# How to passing parameter to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
$(function () {
$('#zucker').slider({
    some code        
    });
});
```

I call it of

```
      <div id="zucker"></div>
```

what possibilies i have to passing parameter to my function

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What is it you're trying to achieve, what isn't working, ... ?

Comment: At present this question doesn't make much sense. What parameters do you want to pass? And to the `ready` handler you've defined, or to the `slider` function, or...? What's `some code`?

Comment: I don't know if i understood your question corectly, it is working good but I need to passing 2 parameters, und I don't know how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#zucker').slider({
        myFirstParameterToSlider: "myFirstValue",
        mySecondParameterToSlider: "mySecondValue"
    });
});
```

To see all possible parameters, look [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#options)